# Trouble importing gym and universe (from OpenAI)

Tags: python, terminal, universe, openai-gym

I installed two packages, [gym](https://github.com/openai/gym) and [universe](https://github.com/openai/universe), but can't import them into my IDE (LiClipse) and I'm not totally sure why. When installed, both were added to the root directory, so I moved them into the same folder as my project file, which includes the python file I'm working in. However, that didn't help at all.

I'm guessing I need to move the folders to the same place all my other python modules/ directories, but when I'm not sure how to access that folder. When I go to see where numpy is installed I get:

['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy']

When I follow that path in terminal, I get to library, but then can't navigate to Frameworks as it apparently doesn't exist.

Am I on the right track here or should I do something else?

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to move the gym and universe folders to any other folder? Assuming that you have installed them the way explained in the [openai docs](https://gym.openai.com/docs). , these will go directly into places where your python interpreter will be able to find out them automatically. So unless I am missing out on some other subtleties of your requirements, I would say just install them correctly, import them into your python program and start using them just like you do with your numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Gym and Universe were being saved as their own folders, and my IDE wasn't checking the location they were saved in for modules to use. To fix I

A) found the location in which Gym and Universe were being saved using the terminal

B) Moved them to the folders my IDE checks for modules. You can find the folders your IDE checks within the settings of your IDE.

When you download modules they usually all save to the same or similar folders that your IDE automatically checks. Mine were saved to a different folder in this particular instance.